# Reference encoding error byte in Python

Tags: python, encoding

Suppose I type `line = line.decode('gb18030;)` and get the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb18030' codec can't decode bytes in position 142-143: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Is there a nice way to automatically get the error bytes? That is, is there a way to get `142` & `143` or `line[142:144]` from a built-in command or module? Since I'm fairly confident that there will be only one such error, at most, per line, my first thought was along the lines of:

```
for i in range(len(line)):
    try:    
        line[i].decode('gb18030')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        error = i
```

I don't know how to say this correctly, but gb18030 has variable byte length so this method fails once it gets to a Chinese character (2 bytes).

Comment: In this context, I'd like to repeat the advice given in answer to your previous question: (1) the gb* decoders are buggy in that they report an illegal 2-byte sequence when the problem is "merely" an illegal lead byte (e.g. 0x80 and 0xff) -- hence 'replace' and 'ignore' options swallow what may be a valid data byte (2) I have debugging code available for exploring "almost decodable but not quite" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `start` and `end` attributes of the caught exception object.

```
u = u'áiuê©'
try:
  l = u.encode('latin-1')
  print repr(l)
  l.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError, e:
  print e
  print e.start, e.end
```

Comment: Why so much code in the try clause?  why not only have the `decode()` there?

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    line = line.decode('gb18030')
except UnicodeDecodeError, e:
    print "Error in bytes %d through %d" % (e.start, e.end)
```